# Celery : task executed so fast that cannot retrieve updated DB

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm using **Cerely**(version 3.0.25) to manage delayed task on my django(version 1.5.4) project.

I got problem when I tried to **retrieve updated DB by celery after saving query**.

Here is sample code. (*views.py*)

```
# import model
from .models import SampleModel

# import celery task
from utils.tasks import GetLastID

# Sample function in view
def save_query():

     # Sample saving query. Let's assume that query.id returns value "7"
     query = SampleModel(field_A="A", field_B="B")
     query.save()

     # Case 1 : this return "6" which is a past 'Last ID value' (not expected)
     GetLastID.apply_async(args=[], countdown=0)

     # Case 2 : this return "7" which is most recent ID value as expected
     GetLastID.apply_async(args=[], countdown=1)
```

In short, I got expected value when I delayed task one second. However, I got not-updated value when I executed celery task without delay.

I think that the problem is "*celery executed so fast that cannot retrieve updated DB*".

How could I **get expected value without delay**? Following is a pseudo code that I thought.

```
(query.save() | GetLastID()).delay()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the code that save the SampleModel in django view function?

Comment: @falsetru Yes, in views.py.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to explicitly commit changes before call the celery task.

Example using [`django.db.transaction.commit_manually`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_manually)

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_manually  # <----
def view(request, ...):
    query = SampleModel(field_A="A", field_B="B")
    query.save()
    transaction.commit()  # <----

    GetLastID.apply_async(args=[])
```

Comment: That seems to be fixing the problem. I can't check the solution right now, so I will adapt this code later and let you know the result. Thanks for your fast answer.